# Can I use a ExpressCard slot as image input?

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, expresscard

I have an old laptop which I would like to use as a secondary monitor for another laptop. While this is typically not possible, I just realized that my old laptop has a ExpressCard slot. It is a [Toshiba Satellite A500 18R](https://icecat.biz/en-in/p/toshiba/psar3e-00w00fsp/satellite-notebooks-satellite+a500-18r-3795755.html).

In Amazon I have found ExpressCard adaptors for USB 3.0 and HDMI to USB 3.0 adaptors. I was wondering if by plugging everything I would be able to use the Toshiba laptop as a secondary monitor.

Does anyone know if that would even be possible?

Comment: Components you are talking about is for connecting another screen (monitor, tv etc.) to computer. You need some solution to transfer images between them - like [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ls04To6LP8)

Comment: Main problem is that the mapin laptop (the one I was to transfer image from) runs ubuntu 16.4 and the one I want to use as second monitor runs Windows 7.

Comment: have a look at this [post](https://askubuntu.com/q/456062)